# how to check the an interface type in c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

i want to convert that line from c# to c++/cli

```
Idocobj is IPart
```

IPart is an interface and Idocobj is an object.Are there any way to do this conversion.

i used this code :

```
Idocobj->GetType() == IPart::typeid
```

but it dosen't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dynamic_cast` to check for "is". Here is an example:

```
using namespace System;
namespace NS
{
  public interface class IFoo
  {
    void Test();
  };

  public ref class Foo : public IFoo
  {
  public: virtual void Test() {}
  };
  public ref class Bar
  {
  public: virtual void Test() {}
  };
}

template<class T, class U> 
bool isinst(U u) {
  return dynamic_cast< T >(u) != nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    NS::Foo^ f = gcnew NS::Foo();
    NS::Bar^ b = gcnew NS::Bar();

    if (isinst<NS::IFoo^>(f))
      Console::WriteLine("f is IFoo");

    if (isinst<NS::IFoo^>(b) == false)
      Console::WriteLine("f is not IFoo");

    Console::ReadKey();
}
```

But normally, you never use "is".... you always want to do something with the check... so normally you should use "as" which directly mapps to `dynamic_cast`:

```
NS::IFoo^ ifoo = dynamic_cast<NS::IFoo^>(f);
if (ifoo != nullptr)
{
  // Do something...
 ifoo->Test();
}
```

Comment: Thks for replying i used the dynamic_cast it fix the problem